# Converting a HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> to a HashMap <String, String>

Tags: java, hashmap

Please, help me convert a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` to `HashMap <String, String>`, where each `ArrayList` should be converted into one `String` that contains the ArrayList's elments.

Comment: What would "the one String" look like?

Comment: I want send this HashMap to the session and display using jstl.

Comment: You need to specify how exactly you want to convert data in `ArrayList<String>` to `String` (some example showing input and result would be nice) and also what part of your code doesn't work as you expect (you have some code right?)

Comment: you want arrayList elements separate with ,?

Comment: Why don't you just call `toString` on the entire Map? That should fulfill your requirements.

Comment: @haraldK Huh?  That would convert the Map to a String, where OP wants to convert to a Map<String,String>.  Steve P. has a correct response.  (Hmm, just noted OP's comment about jstl, so maybe he does want a big String and not a Map<String, String>

Comment: What do you want the string to look like! CSV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is what you are looking for.

```
//HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap;  
//initialized somewhere above

HashMap<String, String> newHashMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : hashMap.entrySet())
{
    newHashMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

Not sure if your issue was with `toString()` or how to iterate over a HashMap, if it was the latter, here's [how to iterate over a map](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-iterate-over-a-map-in-java).

Here's a from-start-to-finish example:

```
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add("The");
    al.add("End");

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("This is", al);

    HashMap<String, String> newHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : hashMap.entrySet())
    {
        newHashMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
    }

    System.out.println(newHashMap.toString());
    //prints {This is=[The, End]}
```